# Be Experienced In

Tags: word-usage

I have a question about the usage of pattern "experienced in" [here](http://www.tmscenterofnewyork.com/insurance-coverage.php):

> Our staff members are highly knowledgeable and ***experienced in the rules*** and limitations of medical insurance...

Would rewriting the sentence:

> Staff members are ***experienced in*** the rules of medical insurance.

as:

> Staff members have ***experience with*** the rules of medical insurance.

be better?

Comment: Yes. The revised one sounds much better.

Comment: It's the wrong verb in the first place - people can be ***familiar*** with "rules", but not *experienced*. If they're experienced in something, it has to be something they *do*. Thus you could be experienced in the *interpretation* or *implementation* of the rules, or *dealing with the rules*, but not directly in the rules themselves.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  So, "*be experienced in standard methods*" is also wrong?

Comment: There are no absolute rules regarding constructions of the general form *to **be experienced** / **have experience** [preposition] X*. Bear in mind that these are figurative extensions from the more literal sense of *experience = undergo, be subjected to, feel*, so as a general principle, *experienced [in, with, etc.] X* works better if ***X*** is an *action* you can undertake (often expressed as a gerund). It's better to say you're *experienced in **using** standard methods* (or perhaps *have experience of/with standard methods*, but that's a bit "iffy").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following sentence implies that the staff members have reached a state of *being experienced*

> Staff members ***are experienced in*** the rules of medical insurance.

This sentence only implies that they have some amount of experience.

> Staff members ***have experience with*** the rules of medical insurance.

The staff members in question can have either a small amount of experience or a large amount of experience and still qualify for the latter, while the former implies that the staff member has reached an implied higher level of experience that specifically qualifies them for the job at hand.

Therefore the revised sentence has a different implied meaning than the original sentence, but grammatically both are correct.